# Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6 with certbot

Tags: ssl-certificate, docker, lets-encrypt, certbot, digital-ocean

I'm trying to update an SSL certificate on digital ocean with the command `certbot renew` But I get this error:

> Problem binding to port 80: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.

running `netstat -plunt` shows that port 80 is been used by 'docker-proxy'.

What can I do to fix this should I stop docker-proxy how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off your http server then try again. When it's done turn your http server back on

Comment: Thanks solved by stopping and restarting the docker container

Comment: @Harry your welcome :)